# MS SQL: How are variables and aliases evaluated within query execution?

Tags: sql-server, parameters, hoisting

I'm working on a MS SQL project, and quite new to SQL in general.

In a query that contains this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.sUserType
FROM @users u
```

And alias (the variable 'u') is being used before a variable has been declared (@param has been previously declared). Then again:

```
SELECT  
    ...,
    aType.hMy as hAssetType,
    ...,
    ...,
    ...,
    ...,
    etc
FROM @users u
        LEFT JOIN somTableName aType on UPPER(u.sAssetType) UPPER(aType.sType)
        LEFT JOIN etc
        LEFT JOIN etc
```

I come from very much a Javascript background, where there is the concept of 'hoisting'.

Q:
Is it possible to discuss SQL queries in terms of being compiled or interpreted?

Q:
Is query execution where vars are defined after usage comparable to Javascript hoisting?

Q:
Also, how does this compare to other implementations of the SQL standard?

----- EDIT -----

Answer below points out that an alias is different to a variable.

A variable needs to be declared before it can be referred to, but an

Comment: what is javascript hoisting ? What does it do ?

Comment: For you to use `FROM @users`, means that the variable was declared previously

Comment: Also, SQL is a declarative language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Absolutely, queries are interpreted and an execution plan for the entire query is chosen by the SQL Engine before execution begins.
2. You are conflating aliases with variables.  In SQL a variable has to be declared before it can be used.  An alias can be referenced "higher up" in a SQL query, and defined "further down", but I doubt it's comparable to "hoisting" whatever that is, because JavaScript is a line-by-line thing, and SQL queries are interpreted as a single set-based operation.
3. You mean how does this vary among different RDBMS?   Not much at all, from the few I've worked with.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not exactly sure what you mean by single set-based operations at this point. Do you mean that queries are considered holistically by the engine before execution?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean.  In JavaScript terms, you might say that the SQL Server engine treats any entire query as a single line of code.

Comment: Javascript is more compiled than interpreted now I believe -  I think that means 'optimized holistically'... But I've never considered execution as line-by-line regardless. Thanks for that

Comment: Been a LONG time since I did JavaScript.  : )